# How one content can collapse others when is on open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code where I used to click on particular `button` to show or hide the contents and it is successfully worked but is not what I want only but also I want when one content is on show `open` there could be no another `open` means that if I show one of the content and trying to show another that the second one will cause the first one was on show to collapse automatically but I failed how can I do that.

**My code**

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("colps");
for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      coll[i].innerHTML = 'open';
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      coll[i].innerHTML = 'close';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 30%;
}
.colps {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.active,
.colps:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.cont {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="colps">open</button>
  <p class="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <button type="button" class="colps">open</button>
  <p class="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <button type="button" class="colps">open</button>
  <p class="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

I crossed around many questions and answers trying to do it myself but I didn't found the solution that's I'm seeking for any help.

Comment: How about a simple jQuery [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/jmt592gd/)? Remember, write less, do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below. I used nested `forEach` and when clicked the button I collapsed all others.

```js
var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".colps");


coll.forEach(p => {
  p.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    coll.forEach(p2 => {
        p2.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
        p2.innerHTML = 'open';
    });
    
    p.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = p.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      p.innerHTML = 'open';
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      p.innerHTML = 'close';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 30%;
}

.colps {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.colps:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.cont {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="colps">open</button>
  <p class="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <button type="button" class="colps">open</button>
  <p class="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <button type="button" class="colps">open</button>
  <p class="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```